# Moving docker image from 1.7 to 17.06

Tags: docker

I tried to move an image that was created with docker 1.7 on Red Hat 6 to a system running docker 17.06.0-ce on Ubuntu 14.04.5. The image appeared to load but after it was loaded I got the message:

```
open /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-import-748740002/repositories: no such file or directory
```

docker images shows it, but with no repo ot tag:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>            <none>              12e143c9efb2        4 weeks ago         6.04GB
```

What is that error and should I expect to be able to move that image over?

Comment: How to move? List the details about that

Comment: I used docker save and docker load

Comment: That is a very old version of docker and I doubt the movement would work. Try pushing it to dockerhub and pulling and see if it works. It may be possible that it still doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You moved the image by copying the `/var/lib/docker` directories, I am guessing? This is not the right way to do it; you should `docker push` your images to a image repo, and then `docker pull` back out from the repo.

You *might* be able to recover by manually re-tagging the image, e.g. `docker tag 12e143c9efb2 mycompany/myimage:version`. But you'll be better off letting Docker manage its own data, and using `docker push` from the Red Hat system and `docker pull` from the Ubuntu system.

Comment: I used docker save and docker load